# Google dfp Frequency cap

Tags: google-dfp

Hi good day I have a line item that will run for a year but will only have a monthly impression of 50 thousand. How can I set this up on google dfp small business.

The frequency cap is per user we don't want it to be per user. Can someone please advice.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is one workaround and one option inside DFP to make this work:

Create an order with a single line item with a running time of just one month and your monthly impression goal. 
You can then copy this single line item 11x times with it's creatives in to the same order and adjust only the start/-enddate. 
The ad unit code, etc. can remain the same in this setup.

If you want to rely on DFP's built in features you can choose a price priority line item, which would allow you to set a daily impression goal. You would need to target this line item type to a special ad unit in order to work. The daily impression goal is of course the amount of impressions you want to serve per month, divided by 30.5.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done.

1. Go to your line item
2. Go down to "Adjust Delivery"
3. Tick "Frequency"
4. In the first field box, add "50,000" to denote your impressions limit and then in the 2nd box, leave it as "1" and then change the default "Day" setting to "Month".
5. Save

This will allow the line to serve to a limit of 50,000 max per month.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply, this was the first step we did unfortunately it did not work. The set up was 600k impression for a year and we wanted it to display 50k impressions per month. We did what you said but their is a limit to the number of impressions you can use. this is the error 50000 impressions per MONTH exceeds the limit of 511.

Comment: My apologies for the late reply! A reason it didn't work could be because FC is set at a user level and DFP figures out there is no way a user would be served 50k imps per month. Usually a FC is set at 1/day/user. The best method would be to set up 12 lines (1/month) at 50k goal each. This way, DFP can plan out its delivery and help you optimize well as well.